# providing free in-app purchases to select people

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an app that is being funded through a donation website that includes rewards. Some of the rewards I want to do is a free set of in-app purchases. Is this possible on google play? Can I manually do discount codes, or is there a systematic way to do it?
Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I have found is to e-mail the APK for the game itself and manage the details in a database, and change the numbers. I'll mark this is the accepted answer, but if someone comes up with something else, I'll happily change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement give-away coupons with redeemable codes for your in-app products using the new in-app promotions Play Store feature:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html

You can create up to 500 promo codes for a month and send them to your supporters.